# how to add ordinary music files on Apple music in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, airdrop

I have a 14 in macbook pro running Monterey and an iphone 13. I also have a 500 MB 10-hour white noise m4a music file. I'm able to airdrop to iphone 13 and play the music in Files app on iphone, but there's no advanced controls like loop or repeating, so I want to somehow play this on my iphone's Music app, which *does* have those advanced controls. However, this is surprisingly difficult.

I tried importing the file to my macbook's music app, but it doesn't automatically sync to my iphone's music app. I also tried enabling "home share" on both iphone and macbook, and was able to finally play the music on my music app on iphone, but it seems with home share that the file it's playing is still the one located on my macbook: I tried putting my macbook to sleep, and it instantly was no longer able to play on my phone.

I also don't have an apple music subscription; I just want to play my own files in apple music. I remember in Itunes this was straightforward, but there's no more itunes anymore, just Apple music, and it seems they strongly encourage subscriptions and don't support the "I just want to play my own files" use case anymore.

How do I just copy a file to iphone and play it on the music app (not files)???

Answer (score 1):

it was extremely non-obvious and hidden, but there is definitely a way to do this. I read the doc on this page: [Sync content between mac and iphone or ipad](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/sync-music-books-and-more-between-devices-mchlde9a31f1/mac).

In particular, I had to connect my phone and macbook using USB, then go to finder and look for my phone in thes sidebar. The first time it wasn't there, but I disconnected and reconnected the USB and it appeared. Then some messages asking me if I trust each device appeared on each, so I just clicked "Trust". Then, I was able to enable syncing for music, and on the apple music app on my phone, I saw the file that I had previously imported to my macbook's music app.

Note that in the "sync" page in finder (from clicking my iphone in the sidebar) you can enable wi-fi syncing, though you must connect and trust at least once with usb in order to be able to access the sync page to do this, [as explained here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/wi-fi-syncing-mchlada1d602/12.0/mac/12.0)